# Как возможно сравнивать значения в python

Tags: python, json, requests, bs4

хотел написать программу которая парсит предметы с одного сайта (csgo.tm) и сравнивает цены в торговой площадке steam , первая часть программы получилось а вот как сравнить додуматься не могу т.к начинающий.

```
result  = []

page = '2'

search = ''

price_on = "0"
price_off = '3000'
url = 'https://market.csgo.com/?            s=pop&t=all&rs='+price_on+';'+price_off+'&search='+search+'&sd=desc'

print(url)
headers ={
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36 OPR/40.0.2308.81',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'DNT': '1',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch',
'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'
}

def data_colected():
responses = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup= bs(responses.text, "html.parser")
all_links = soup.find_all('a' , class_='item hot')
if all_links == []:
    print('неверно')

else:

    #all_links = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'item hot'}).text
    for link in all_links:
        url1 = 'https://market.csgo.com' + link['href']
        #print(url1)
        responses = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
        soup= bs(responses.text, "html.parser")
        full_name = soup.find('div', class_='item-h1').find('h1').text
        full_float = soup.find('div', class_='item-h1').find('span').text
        full_price= soup.find('div', class_='ip-bestprice').__str__().replace('<div class="ip-    bestprice">', '').replace('<small></small> </div>', '').strip()
        if full_price == 'None':
            full_price = 'ПРОЧЕРК'
        #normal_price = soup.find('div', id="rectanglestats" )
        img = soup.find('div',class_='ip-pic')
        img = img.findChildren('img')[0]                            
        img = img['src']
        full_name= full_name.__str__().replace('|', '')
        if full_price == None:
            return
        else:
            result.append(

                {
                    "img": img,
                    "full_name": full_name,
                    "full_float": full_float,
                    'full_price': full_price,
                    'url': url1

                }
            )
            print(img)
            print(("Название -  ") + full_name)
            print(("Качество -  ") + full_float)
            print(("Цена - ") + full_price + (' рублей'))
            print(('ССылка на товар - ') + url1)

with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
    json.dump(result, file, indent=4 , ensure_ascii=False)
print(len(result))`
```

вот так я хочу попробовать реализовать

```
item_name = ""
item_name2 = ""
item_float = '3'
stattrak = "" 
url_steam ="https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Exterior%5B%5D=tag_WearCategory"+item_float+"&appid=730&q="+stattrak+"+"+item_name+'+'+item_name2
```

Comment: Для сравнения надо использовать `>`, `<` и `==`. Сравнивать цену на площадке с целевой ценой, например. Или переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Импорты всех используемых библиотек должны быть в коде. И поясните - что и с чем вы собираетесь сравнивать и что делать с результатом сравнения?

Comment: Да , я  что то криво все описал , 1 используемые библиотеки это : Json , BS4 , requests , lxml
2. я получаю данные с парсинга в словарь result, такие как название предмета и  цена на сайте , и я хочу сверить эти цены с сайта с цена в стиме и  дополнить словарь result полученным результатом.
Вроде попытался описать что я хочу, заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: в посте в конце я добавил как я хотел реализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Сразу скажу, пока это не ответ. Пока это только попытка выяснить, как и с чем Вы хотите сравнивать данные. Хотя я и использовал для хранения данных JSON, это не самый лучший формат для хранения сравниваемых и обновляемых данных (предлагаю для начала освоить хотя бы `sqlite`, но об этом чуть позже)*
***Итак: Давайте сначала корректно распарсим и соберем данные:***

> Для начала нам понадобится 
> `pip install requests simplejson bs4 fake-useragent tqdm --upgrade`

```py
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup, Tag
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util import Retry
from urllib.parse import unquote
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import re
import simplejson as json

# Для удобства сборки элементов создадим dataclass
@dataclass()
class Weapon:
    url: str
    img: str = None
    full_name: str = None
    appearance: str = None
    full_price: float = .0
    currency: str = None

    # Свойство класса не попадает в словарь
    # при преобразовании экземпляра класса в словарь,
    # но его можно использовать при обработке экземпляра класса
    @property
    def item_id(self):
        # Здесь мы создадим ID экземпляра, для того,
        # чтобы каждый экземпляр можно было идентифицировать
        # и выбрать для сравнения
        return re.sub(r'^.*?(?<=item/)([\d-]+\d).*$', r'\1', self.url)

    # Когда Вы расскажете, как Вы хотите сравнить две сущности
    # Здесь появится метод
    # def __eq__():

# Для того чтобы не морочиться с созданием заголовка User-Agent
# есть специальная библиотека fake-useragent
ua = UserAgent()

base_url = 'https://market.csgo.com'

#  Для обращения к сайтам при парсинге
#  лучше всего использовать одну сессию для всех запросов.
#  Иначе Вы рискуете быть заблокированными на сайте.
#  (Справедливости ради это не панацея, владельцы сайтов не
#  сильно любят когда их ресурсы парсят, но вероятность снижается)

s = Session()
s.mount(
    base_url,
    HTTPAdapter(
        max_retries=Retry(
            total=5,
            read=2,
            connect=2,
            backoff_factor=.005,
            allowed_methods=['GET']
        )
    )
)

# Добавляем User-Agent в заголовки сессии
s.headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': ua.random,
    }
)

# На этом сайте можно выбрать язык задав значение для cookie
s.cookies.setdefault(
    '_language', 'ru'
)

# Пояснение зачем оно здесь ниже
# s.proxies = {
#    'https': 'socks5://localhost:1080'
# }

# Так-же можно задать валюту, в которой Вы будете получать ценны
# Кстати, без использования сессии фиг бы у нас это прокатило
s.get(
    base_url + '/currency/switch/rub'
)

# Итак, поехали...
response = s.get(
    base_url,
    params={
        's': 'pop',
        't': 'all'
    }
)
# 1. Получаем содержимое главной страницы
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')


def weapon_item(pag_url_tag: Tag):
    # 3.1 Создаем экземпляр класса и сразу присваиваем значение параметру url.
    weapon = Weapon(
        url=base_url + unquote(pag_url_tag.get('href'))
    )

    # 3.2 запрашиваем содержимое страницы товара
    p_response = s.get(
        weapon.url
    )
    # и создаем суп
    p_soup = Soup(p_response.content, 'html.parser')

    # 3.3 Определение валюты цены можно было и не делать,
    #   мы ее и так в самом начале определили, но можно и оставить (так надежнее)
    if currency_tag := p_soup.find('div', class_=['currency-selector__item', 'active']):
        weapon.currency = currency_tag.get_text(strip=True)
    
    # 3.4 Ищем Таг заголовка 
    #   (предварительная проверка наличия тагов, перед получением их параметров, 
    #   позволяет не натыкаться на исключения при их отсутствии)
    if header_tag := p_soup.find('div', {'class': 'item-h1'}):
        
        # 3.5 Определяем название и присваиваем значение параметру класса 
        if title_tag := header_tag.find('h1'):
            weapon.full_name = title_tag.get_text(strip=True)
        
        # 3.6 Определяем состояние и присваиваем значение параметру класса 
        if appearance_tag := header_tag.find('div', {'class': 'item-appearance'}):
            weapon.appearance = appearance_tag.get_text(strip=True)
    
    # 3.7 Определяем цену и присваиваем значение параметру класса 
    if price_tag := p_soup.find('div', {'class': 'ip-bestprice'}):
        weapon.full_price = float(price_tag.get_text(strip=True).replace(' ', ''))
        
    # 3.8 Определяем ссылку на изображение и присваиваем значение параметру класса 
    if img_block := p_soup.find('div', {'class': 'ip-pic'}):
        if img_tag := img_block.find('img'):
            weapon.img = unquote(img_tag.get('src'))

    return weapon

# 4. Создаем словарь где используем в качестве 
#   ключа для элемента значение созданного нами свойства класса
one_page_elements = {
    elem.item_id: asdict(elem)
    for elem in
    # 2. Находим все ссылки на страницы товаров                     ^
    # 3. К каждому элементу списка применяем созданную заранее      |
    #   функцию обработки и получения содержимого страницы товара ---
    map(weapon_item, tqdm(soup.find_all('a', class_='item')))
    # tqdm для наглядности. 
    # В ходе выполнения будем видеть бар (как показано ниже)
    # и не будем сучить ножками в нетерпении )))
}


# Кстати на счет нелюбви порталов к парсерам.
# Была идея использовать здесь многопоточность но
# Быстро получил бан, пришлось прикручивать прокси

# 5. Сохраняем в JSON

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json.dump(
        one_page_elements,
        json_file,
        ensure_ascii=False,
        indent=2
    )
```

`100%|██████████| 65/65 [00:20<00:00,  3.11it/s]`

```json
{
  "310780755-302028390": {
    "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/310780755-302028390-Nova | Predator (Well-Worn)/",
    "img": "https://cdn.csgo.com//item/Nova | Predator (Well-Worn)/300.png",
    "full_name": "Nova | Хищник",
    "appearance": "Поношенное",
    "full_price": 1.72,
    "currency": "RUB"
  },
...
  "3608111561-188530139": {
    "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/3608111561-188530139-★ Nomad Knife | Case Hardened (Well-Worn)/",
    "img": "https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf3ObcdTJN_uO3hb-EnvvxN4Tck29Y_chOhujT8om7jVawrUFtMjr3ItCdIwZtNFmE_QXqwenp1JHouJ6YnyM2vSkgtC6JzAv33087rDOhDg",
    "full_name": "★ Нож «Бродяга» | Поверхностная закалка",
    "appearance": "Поношенное",
    "full_price": 13372.34,
    "currency": "RUB"
  }
}
```

#### Внимание! Вопрос(ы)

1. Откуда мы будем брать данные с которыми будем сравнивать?
2. Что будем делать после сравнения данных?
3. Нужно ли (думаю что да) собирать данные со всех страниц со списком товаров, или можно ограничится одной?
   ...

> Пока все... продолжение после ответов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , много чего не знал . 
Моя идея заключалось в том что-бы я парсил данные с сайта csgo.tm , затем полученные данные (названия скина и его качество ) вводил в стиме и смотрел сколько там данная вещь стоит и добавлял это значение в json файл

Comment: @FriskAndou, могу я попросить Вас дать ссылку в стиме, откуда Вы будете брать данные для сравнения?

Comment: @FriskAndou, и еще хотелось бы уточнить как Вы предполагаете хранить цены из стима. Вы хотите каждый раз перезаписывать пару цен (сайт, стим) или сохранять историю сравнений? И если я Вас правильно понял, что ключевыми данными для сравнения являются "названия скина и его качество" то тут может быть нюанс. Судя по тому, что к названиям на сайте добавляется уникальный индекс, то предполагается, что название может быть не уникальным (это для подумать).

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&appid=730&q=slate  , ссылка на стим

Comment: нужно будет каждый раз перезаписывать пару цен (сайт, стим)

Comment: У меня возникла идея , но я не могу понять как ее правильно будет реализовать, стим в своей ссылке имеет название вещи и его качество , я хочу достать из json файла полное имя предмета а так- же его качество , после чего я хотел парсить ссылку которую получил

Comment: @FriskAndou, идея не плоха, до вечера ее покурите, вечерком вернемся к разговору, если он будет для Вас еще актуален. Только прошу, посмотрите в моем коде как задаются параметры для запросов и не собирайте вручную монструозных ссылок.

Comment: да , я сейчас разбираюсь в вашем коде , спасибо за помощь

Comment: @FriskAndou, думаю этот ресурс будет Вам полезен https://docs-python.ru/

Comment: Думаю да , спасибо

Comment: попробовал разобраться в вашем коде , попытался реализовать в своем коде смену валюты и языка , но что то не вышло.
я не смог разобраться что происходит в этом участке кода -
s = Session()
s.mount(
    base_url,
    HTTPAdapter(
        max_retries=Retry(
            total=5,
            read=2,
            connect=2,
            backoff_factor=.005,
            allowed_methods=['GET']
        )
    )
)
с 27 линии

Comment: и так-же возник вопрос в 86 строке кода , как в ссылку вписывается параметры фильтра такие как pop и all
response = s.get(
    base_url,
    params={
        's': 'pop',
        't': 'all'
    }
)

Comment: @FriskAndou, по поводу последнего вопроса - это эквивалентно записи `https://market.csgo.com?s=pop&t=all` Просто когда их (параметров) много, так проще их записывать и не нужно заморачиваться с конкатенацией их в одну строку. Код получается читабельный, что улучшает его восприятие как самим автором, так и другими. Насчет адаптера почитайте доки по `requests` и `urllib3`

Comment: Понятно , с адаптером разобрался