# Как возможно обойти ошибку <Response [429]>

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4, useragent

Всем привет , писал парсер для вещей из cs, но на этапе парсинга выдает ошибку <Response [429]>
как возможно обойти данную ошибку  , попробовал через fake user agent , ?

в файле Json находиться название и качество предмета пример -

```
[
    {
        "img": "https://cdn.csgo.com//item/Souvenir%20PP-Bizon%20%7C%20Candy%20Apple%20%28Field-Tested%29/300.png",
        "full_name": "Souvenir PP-Bizon  Candy Apple",
        "full_float": "Field-Tested",
        "full_price": "1.3 USD",
        "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/4629599872-188530139-Souvenir%20PP-Bizon%20%7C%20Candy%20Apple%20%28Field-Tested%29/"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://cdn.csgo.com//item/Souvenir%20G3SG1%20%7C%20New%20Roots%20%28Battle-Scarred%29/300.png",
        "full_name": "Souvenir G3SG1  New Roots (Battle-Scarred)",
        "full_float": "Закалённое в боях",
        "full_price": "2 USD",
        "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/4913593285-188530139-Souvenir%20G3SG1%20%7C%20New%20Roots%20%28Battle-Scarred%29/"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://cdn.csgo.com//item/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Five-SeveN%20%7C%20Kami%20%28Field-Tested%29/300.png",
        "full_name": "StatTrak™ Five-SeveN  Kami",
        "full_float": "Field-Tested",
        "full_price": "1.579 USD",
        "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/310791931-188530170-StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Five-SeveN%20%7C%20Kami%20%28Field-Tested%29/"
    }
]
```

ссылка на сайт : https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q=M4A4++Radiation+Hazard++(%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

```
from email import header
from fileinput import close
import json
from random import random
from turtle import st
from wsgiref import headers
from requests import Session
from unittest import skip
from urllib3.util import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import lxml

with open('result.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
for item in data:

    ua=UserAgent()
    print(ua)
    sesi_steam = Session()


    sesi_steam.headers.update({'User-Agent': ua.random})


    _full_name=item.get("full_name")
    _full_name1= _full_name.__str__().replace('(Field-Tested)', ' ').replace('(Well-Worn)', ' ').replace('(Battle-Scarred)', ' ').replace('(Minimal Wear)', ' ').replace('(Factory New)', ' ')
    _full_float=item.get("full_float")

    search_float = _full_float.__str__().replace(' ', '+')
    searching =_full_name1.__str__().replace(' ', '+')
    url_steam = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q="+searching +'('+search_float+')'

    print(url_steam)
    responses = sesi_steam.get(url_steam)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(responses)
    soup= bs(responses.text, "html.parser")
    steam_item_price = soup.find('div', class_="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price")
    print(steam_item_price)
```

Comment: "Как возможно обойти ошибку <Response [429]>|" А кто вам сказал, что это ошибка?

Comment: Я понимаю что это не совсем ошибка , но сайт с которого пытаюсь взять данные блокирует , это я имел ввиду.

Comment: А почему блокирует?

Comment: Частые запросы т.к мне нужно получать цены для каждого предмета

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1237266/470333

Comment: Да , читал данный пост ,  но не помогло

Comment: Еще появилась проблема - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' это как то возможно обойти , а именно если будет попадаться объект noneType его скипали ,

Comment: И так чисто из любопытства, нафига здесь столько импорта?

Comment: а я просто как черновой вариант использую

Comment: Namerek , спасибо вам еще раз.

Comment: Namerek, а у вас в коде вы получаете у всех предметов цену ?

Comment: @FriskAndou, нет, там иногда даже если в браузере смотреть цену не показывает. Пишет что проблема с их торговыми ботами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продолжение [поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431550/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-python) в котором я Вам начал отвечать:

```py
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import List
from urllib.parse import unquote

import requests
import simplejson as json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup, Tag
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from urllib3.util import Retry


# Для удобства сборки элементов создадим dataclass
@dataclass()
class Weapon:
    url: str
    img: str = None
    full_name: str = None
    appearance: str = None
    full_price: float = .0

    # Добавил свойство классу 
    # для хранения цены steam
    steam_price: float = .0
    currency: str = None

    # Свойство класса не попадает в словарь
    # при преобразовании экземпляра класса в словарь,
    # но его можно использовать при обработке экземпляра класса
    @property
    def item_id(self):
        # Здесь мы создадим ID экземпляра, для того,
        # чтобы каждый экземпляр можно было идентифицировать
        # и выбрать для сравнения
        return re.sub(r'^.*?(?<=item/)([\d-]+\d).*$', r'\1', self.url)

    @property
    def search_key(self):
        return f'{self.full_name}({self.appearance})'

# Для того чтобы не морочиться с созданием заголовка User-Agent
# есть специальная библиотека fake-useragent
ua = UserAgent()

base_url = 'https://market.csgo.com'

#  Для обращения к сайтам при парсинге
#  лучше всего использовать одну сессию для всех запросов.
#  Иначе Вы рискуете быть заблокированными на сайте.
#  (Справедливости ради это не панацея, владельцы сайтов не
#  сильно любят когда их ресурсы парсят, но вероятность снижается)

s = Session()
s.mount(
    base_url,
    HTTPAdapter(
        max_retries=Retry(
            total=5,
            read=2,
            connect=2,
            backoff_factor=.005,
            allowed_methods=['GET']
        )
    )
)

# Добавляем User-Agent в заголовки сессии
s.headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': ua.random,
    }
)

# На этом сайте можно выбрать язык задав значение для cookie
s.cookies.setdefault(
    '_language', 'en'
)


# Так-же можно задать валюту, в которой Вы будете получать ценны
# Кстати, без использования сессии фиг бы у нас это прокатило
s.get(
    base_url + '/currency/switch/usd'
)

# Итак, поехали...
response = s.get(
    base_url,
    params={
        's': 'pop',
        't': 'all'
    }
)
# 1. Получаем содержимое главной страницы
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')


def weapon_item(pag_url_tag: Tag):
    # 3.1 Создаем экземпляр класса и сразу присваиваем значение параметру url.
    weapon = Weapon(
        url=base_url + unquote(pag_url_tag.get('href'))
    )

    # 3.2 запрашиваем содержимое страницы товара
    p_response = s.get(
        weapon.url
    )
    # и создаем суп
    p_soup = Soup(p_response.content, 'html.parser')

    # 3.3 Определение валюты цены можно было и не делать,
    #   мы ее и так в самом начале определили, но можно и оставить (так надежнее)
    if currency_tag := p_soup.find('div', class_=['currency-selector__item', 'active']):
        weapon.currency = currency_tag.get_text(strip=True)

    # 3.4 Ищем Таг заголовка
    #   (предварительная проверка наличия тагов, перед получением их параметров,
    #   позволяет не натыкаться на исключения при их отсутствии)
    if header_tag := p_soup.find('div', {'class': 'item-h1'}):

        # 3.5 Определяем название и присваиваем значение параметру класса
        if title_tag := header_tag.find('h1'):
            weapon.full_name = title_tag.get_text(strip=True)

        # 3.6 Определяем состояние и присваиваем значение параметру класса
        if appearance_tag := header_tag.find('div', {'class': 'item-appearance'}):
            weapon.appearance = appearance_tag.get_text(strip=True)

    # 3.7 Определяем цену и присваиваем значение параметру класса
    if price_tag := p_soup.find('div', {'class': 'ip-bestprice'}):
        weapon.full_price = float(price_tag.get_text(strip=True).replace(' ', ''))

    # 3.8 Определяем ссылку на изображение и присваиваем значение параметру класса
    if img_block := p_soup.find('div', {'class': 'ip-pic'}):
        if img_tag := img_block.find('img'):
            weapon.img = unquote(img_tag.get('src'))

    return weapon


# 4. Создаем словарь где используем в качестве
#   ключа для элемента значение созданного нами свойства класса
one_page_elements: List[Weapon] = [*map(weapon_item, tqdm(soup.find_all('a', class_='item')))]

base_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com'
for item in tqdm(one_page_elements):
    # Здесь получилось избежать блокировки когда 
    # заменил сессию на отдельные запросы 
    # со сменой User-Agent для каждого запроса.

    response = requests.get(
        base_url + '/market/search',
        params={
            'appid': 730,
            'q': item.search_key
        },
        headers={
            'User-Agent': ua.random,
        }
    )

    item_soup = Soup(
        response.content, 'html.parser'
    )
    if price_tag := item_soup.find(
            'span', {'class': 'normal_price', 'data-price': re.compile(r'^\d+$')}
    ):
        str_price_value = price_tag.get('data-price')
        item.steam_price = int(str_price_value) / 100

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json.dump(
        [*map(asdict, one_page_elements)],
        json_file,
        ensure_ascii=False,
        indent=2
    )
```

> Большинство комментариев из предыдущего поста

---

```json
[
  {
    "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/2736244761-188530139-M4A4 | Neo-Noir (Battle-Scarred)/",
    "img": "https://cdn.csgo.com//item/M4A4 | Neo-Noir (Battle-Scarred)/300.png",
    "full_name": "M4A4 | Neo-Noir",
    "appearance": "Battle-Scarred",
    "full_price": 3.645,
    "steam_price": 3.64,
    "currency": "USD"
  },
...
  {
    "url": "https://market.csgo.com/item/1813198903-188530139-Glock-18 | Wasteland Rebel (Field-Tested)/",
    "img": "https://cdn.csgo.com//item/Glock-18 | Wasteland Rebel (Field-Tested)/300.png",
    "full_name": "Glock-18 | Wasteland Rebel",
    "appearance": "Field-Tested",
    "full_price": 4.536,
    "steam_price": 4.61,
    "currency": "USD"
  }
]
```